# JavaScript Text is not submitting form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form called signup. I decided rather than having a button, I would have text with the use of JavaScript to submit, however the form is not submitting.

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('signup').submit();">Finished</a>
```

Comment: You should probably post your HTML too.

Comment: As well as looking at the error console. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: What exactly led to your decision of using an anchor instead of a form submit button? You could still style the button to look just like a normal link while preserving the native, intuitive and accessible functionality.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you should separate your Javascript from your HTML.  [Read More](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/)
2. You should post more code e.g. HTML.

Here's a working example to get a form to submit:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="signup">

</form>

<a class="submit" href="#">Submit</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
var form = document.querySelector('#signup');
var submitBtn = document.querySelector('a.submit');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    form.submit();
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hpg6mnnr/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you are looking for with this

```
<a href="" onclick="signup.submit();">Finished</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try achieving your objective using the javascript `onclick` event handler. Let me explain it to you with the help of an example, as below

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="google.com" id="link">Google</a>
        <script>
            function f1() {
                alert("f1 called");
                //function f1()'s alert demonstrating additional functionality    
            }
            window.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById("link").onclick = function fun() {
                    alert("hello");
                    f1();
                    //executing an initial "hello" alert
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here we create a link and give it an ID of `link`. Suppose we need it to execute some functionality when it's clicked. All fine for now.

Now after the document is loaded (as demonstrated by `window.onload`) we wait for the link to be clicked. If it's clicked, we execute the `onclick` event which gives an alert "Hello". Further suppose you wanted to execute some extra functionality with the click of your link (like submission of a form, as in your case), so we demonstrate it here using the `f1()` method. As you might see we execute all of these simultaneously simply by using the onclick event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have several ways to do it!

Firstly verify if there is not another HTML element with the same id as you form, because if it has, you have two problems, one your HTML is not well formatted, second it may be defined first than the  tag and of course, the document.getElementById('signup') will catch it firstly. Also if the page hasn't been loaded by complete, it won't find the element, try (see ***form*** down below):

```
window.onload = function () {
    var aBtn = document.getElementById('myA');
    aBtn.onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('submit').submit();
    }
}
```

Another reason but less probable is, your active scripting (javascript for example) may be disable.

Verify it just in case:
Internet Options -> Security Tab -> Custom Level -> Scripting -> Active Scripting -> [Enable]

I've just copied your code and it worked for me.
E.g.:

```
<form id="signup" action="http://google.com">
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('signup').submit();">go</a>
</form>
```

You also can use *onclick="document.getElementById('signup').submit();"* or go with a button or input type="submit"

E.g.:

```
<form id="signup" action="http://google.com">
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('signup').submit();">go</a>
    <input type="submit" value="go2">
    <button>go3</button>
</form>
```

Well, there is other ways to do it but I think those are enough!